# unique leaves behind duplicates

Tags: uniq

After running uniq on this file the output is unchanged.

"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    mathematics
"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    mathematics
"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    non-fiction
"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    non-fiction
"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    quiz-show
"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    quiz-show
"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    word-game
"Celebrity Countdown" (1998)    word-game

Comment: maybe there are spaces at the end?

Comment: There is no whitespace at the end.

Comment: I think it was because there is different kind of whitespace between the year and the last word.